# Method for action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller which contains an action:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

    def action_1
        @user = User.find_by(uid: params[:uid])
        @user.votes.pluck(:author_uid).delete(current_user.uid)
        current_user.user_votes.pluck(:recipient_uid).delete(@user.uid)
        redirect_to root_url
    end

end
```

Which method should it have when I call it in view file:

```
= link_to 'Dislike', { controller: "votes", action: "action_1", uid: friend.uid }, method: "WHICH???"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same method which we used in rails 3. i.e. 'GET'
In rails 4 only update action is change with method 'PATCH' and 'PUT' is also working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the rails router know there is a controller action you can access. So you need to create the entry for it in your routes file to have access to it in the views.

Something like:

```
resources :votes do
  get 'action_1', on: :collection
end
```

Or another type of action, depending on its purpose (see [REST methods](https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html))

Then you can use `action_1_votes_url(uid: friend.uid)` or `action_1_votes_path(uid: friend.uid)` in your views

Answer (score 0):

You have VotesController which is dedicated for Vote resource, and the purpose of `action_1` is to delete from such resource. So there is no need to make a custom action name.

The best action name for this case is `delete`.

And then the link method would be `delete` as well.